# WebDriverError: Cannot define class using reflection

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, gulp-protractor

I am using gulp-angular-protractor for end-to-end testing of my web app. I am getting the following error recently but earlier it used to work perfectly.

[image]

Any help to fix this issue will be appreciated.

Details:

```
OS - Ubuntu 16.04,
node - v6.12.2,
npm - v3.10.10,
Vagrant - v1.9.3,
karma - v0.13.22,
gulp-angular-protractor - v1.1.1,
protractor - v5.1.2,
webdriver-manager - v12.0.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `java-common` and installing `openjdk-8-jre` fixed the issue for me.

To remove `java-common` and its dependencies, run below command

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove java-common
```

To install `openjdk-8-jre`, run below command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Additionally, if you have more than one Java versions installed on your system. Run below command set the default Java

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and type in a number to select a Java version.
[image]